# Differentiate between SSH connection and authentication in Bash / Python

Tags: python, bash, ssh, fabric

This isn't tied to a specific code sample that I have, but many of them.  I'm using Python Fabric to make connections to various servers over SSH from a single host that I'm running my script on. Sometimes it connects just fine and that is the end of it. However, sometimes it can make a connection but gives me a "[serverName] Login password for 'userUser'" error. I don't have access to this server, so even though the connection is being made, I can't authenticate to it. Is there any way to make Bash / Fab / Python realize that I can't connect?

Comment: Can you maybe include one code sample and what you hope to get out of it? I don't know if your question is "How can I differentiate between a connection failure and an authentication failure?", "How can I handle a connection failure from within Fabric?", "How can I tell from bash that `fab` encountered a connection failure?" or something else

Answer (score 0):

I would investigate the following ssh_config options:

```
KbdInteractiveAuthentication no
PasswordAuthentication no
```

See `man ssh_config` for more info on these options.

You can set these options in your ~/.ssh/config file or on the ssh command line using `-o`. I imagine using the ~/.ssh/config file would be transparent to Fabric.